# problems installing sqlite3-rubygem and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have recently updated my mac to snow leopard and am having a terrible time configuring it for rails development. I have followed the tutorial at hivelogic (http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard) and am being returned with the following error. I have also attempted to install sqlite3-ruby gem and am returned with identical issues. I have tried uninstalling the whole build and reinstalling it. I have also tried working with macports. What is the next step?

```
michael-orcutts-macbook:src michaelorcutt$ sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql

Password:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
```

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql

checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
 --with-mysql-config
 --without-mysql-config
 --with-mysql-dir
 --with-mysql-include
 --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
 --with-mysql-lib
 --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-mlib
 --without-mlib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-zlib
 --without-zlib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-socketlib
 --without-socketlib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-nsllib
 --without-nsllib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-mygcclib
 --without-mygcclib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your MySQL Server version. You need to install the 64-bit version.